# How do I Google Plus and Facebook Demo opacity Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, demo, google-plus

Recently Google+ and Facebook have added a nice feature that when a user first logs in and there are new features available it displays it as a demo mode of some sort highlighting the element in question and darkening or changing opacity on the rest of the screen as a means to focus on that element. It also shows step by step tooltips for the demo.

Does anybody know of an open source script or jquery plugin that does this already?

Answer (score 2):

They basically block the UI and show an overlay on top of the whole page. You can try `jQuery` `blockUI` plugin it will help you block the page and then you can show an overlay on top of it.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI

Comment: Thanks for the reply this may be useful as well for a few other needs on my current project

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, so I made one: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/A9AAa/

It's pretty simple, call `spotlightOn` and pass the element on which the "spotlight" should "shine" as an argument. Call `spotlightOff` to turn the spotlight off.

It should degrade gracefully.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it could be made so easily